# Demonstrando um ataque slowloris em servidor apache usando Python

Tags: python, apache, segurança, ddos

Eu tenho o dump de rede (arquivo no formato PCAP capturado com tcpdump) de uma "conversa" entre o servidor atacado (web server Apache: 192.168.1.2) e os clientes maliciosos:
[image: PCAP]

O ataque foi uma simulação em laboratório de negação de serviço com *slowloris*.

Já sei que o ataque foi efetivo pois nos logs do apache (error.log) consta o código 403 (*timeout*).

EU desejo mostrar que isso (a negação de serviço) foi ocasionada pelo *slowloris*.

Pensei em utilizar o script no arquivo PCAP:

[attack_measure.py](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6016559efa40858d74e8dc61f3f00bb)

cuja saída será:

```
print("0 envio e recepção balanceados.")
print("+1 todos os pacotes estão sendo enviados ao servidor.")
print("-1  todos os pacotes estão sendo enviados pelo servidor.")
print("Um número positivo muito grande indica que o servidor parou de responder.")
```

Vocês acham uma boa abordagem?

O que devo verificar no PCAP para garantir que a negação de serviço foi decorrente do *slowloris*   buffer do apache cheio (or TCP WINDOW)?

Li artigos onde diziam que o ataque *slowloris* era apenas para Apache (erro 408:timeout) mas eu rodei contra IIS 8 e funcionou (erro 404). *Slowloris* explora o *handshake* no TCP usando tamanho de janela pequeno, certo? Ou seja, explora PROTOCOLO e não apenas aplicacao. Concordam?

Comment: Olhar o window é sempre uma excelente ideia em ataques slowloris você vai notar janelas com o mesmo tamanho sempre, uma outra característica que você vai notar será um buraco no log de alguns milissegundos seguido de uma grande quantidade de conexões simultâneas, isso geralmente segue um padrão, poderá ser observado no sniffer e ser classificado como um ataque do tipo slowloris ...

Comment: @ederwander: Li artigos onde dizia que slowloris era apenas para Apache mas eu rodei contra IIS e funcionou. Slowloris explora o handshake no TCP usando tamanho de janela pequeno, certo? Ou seja, explora PROTOCOLO e não apenas aplicacao. Concorda?

Comment: Sobre o IIS, ele funciona sim, porém é muito menos eficaz, normalmente a maquina atacante deverá ter capacidade de criar muitos milhares de requisições enquanto que apache 1ou2 seria mais fácil executar um ataque bem sucessido.

Answer (score 12):

**A abordagem está correta, o script também.**

Porém eu partiria de algo um pouco mais robusto como:

---

**Slowloris.py**

https://github.com/gkbrk/slowloris

Basicamente um ataque de negação de serviço HTTP que afeta servidores de thread. Funciona assim:

1. Começa fazendo muitas solicitações HTTP.
2. Envia cabeçalhos periodicamente a cada 15s p/ manter as conexões abertas.
3. Nunca fecha a conexão a menos que o servidor o faça. Se o servidor fecha uma conexão, Slowloris cria uma novamente.
4. Em teoria isso esgota o pool de threads servidores e o servidor não pode responder a outras pessoas.

---

**Ou PyLoris** o mais famoso na comunidade Python
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyloris/files/pyloris/

A diferença do acima é que o PyLoris pode utilizar proxies SOCKS e conexões SSL e pode segmentar protocolos como HTTP, FTP, SMTP, IMAP e Telnet.

Além de uma bela UI feita em Tkinter.

---

Pois a negação de serviço através da técnica Slowloris, apesar de ser muito interessante tecnicamente ela é pouco eficaz.

Visto que a maioria dos Servidores consegue lidar bem com requisições incompletas com o caso do IIS.

**EDIT**: Incompleta seria o termo errado, pois muitas ferramenta slowloris fazem requisições completas e válidas, apenas tentam manter essa conexão aberta.

**Então IIS Seria invulnerável?**

Até onde sei IIS não é invulnerável, mas é muito difícil um ataque assim. a Banda do atacante e recursos do atacante terá que ser iguais do atacado. Justamente o contrário do que o Slowloris pretende.
Veja que em ataques contra IIS o sistema precisa ficar recriando pacotes, visto que o mesmo da um timeout.
nginx e Squid também entram como difíceis de serem atacados com essa técnica.

**Update**: Após alguns anos, testei novamente a ferramenta contra meu servidor interno de IIS 10 (Windows 2016 Standard) e depois de 6000 requisições o mesmo estava tranquilo, sem nenhum problema. OBS: Sem ter feito nenhuma configuração extra nele, foi instalado como default, visto que é o servidor interno aqui da empresa.

**Contra quem é eficaz?**

Ele é muito eficaz em Apaches versões antigas 1.x e 2.x
E alguns outros tipos de servidores que já estão em desuso ou obsoletos.

Veja que todas as técnicas hoje de DDoS já não utilizam mais essa técnica, que apesar de sofisticada já não é eficaz, hoje os DDoS são na força bruta.

**Guardando o log do ataque**

Você pode armazenar a saída do `slowloris.py` para verificar toda vez que der 403, assim confirmando o ataque bem sucedido. seja através de armazenamento do `log` ou `Logging.debug`.

Comment: Sei que foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta mas como seria esse ataque força bruta? Como ele é diferente deste que você explicou?

Comment: força bruta é fazer mais requisições que o servidor pode aguentar com diversos dispositivos..e são requisições verdadeiras, igual a receita federal, ele cai em época de imposto de renda, muita gente acessando. E ñ tem como negar esses pedidos pois são verdadeiros e de máquinas diferentes.
O maior ataque dos que vi foi ano passado com 1 bilhão de dispositivos (60% sendo câmeras ips que foram hackeadas e deixadas como zumbi) Alem de milhares de pcs, todos eles sincronizaram que em tal dia tal hora acessaria um site

Comment: Ah sim entendi, obrigado pelas explicações :D